# DNS sub-domain migration from Digitalocean to Amazon route 53 can't be reached

Tags: dns, subdomain, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

Our DNS `qianalysis.com` is hosted in [Digitalocean](https://cloud.digitalocean.com). I need to move the subdomain `aws.qianalysis.com` to Amazon route 53 and point this subdomain to an Amzaon elastic-loadbalancer instance `http://a1626874f2f1011e7937712000d3b863-200559730.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`. I have done the below steps according to do this documentation of Amazon route 53:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html

1. Created a hosted zone for the subdomain `aws.qianalysis.com` in amazon route 53.
2. Then, created an `A` record set which alias the ELB instance stated above.
3. After that I added the 4 Name Servers of the Amazon route 53 hosted zone `aws.qianalysis.com` in our main domain at Digitalocean as NS records. The Name Servers are: `ns-842.awsdns-41.net., ns-244.awsdns-30.com., ns-1514.awsdns-61.org., ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk.`

But if I now try to access `aws.qianalysis.com` through browser, the result is:

```
site can’t be reached

aws.qianalysis.com took too long to respond.
```

After that I tried to do some troubleshoot to find out if the DNS was configured properly and have run the below queries:

```
$ nslookup aws.qianalysis.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   aws.qianalysis.com
Address: 52.207.24.56
Name:   aws.qianalysis.com
Address: 34.202.99.171

$ nslookup a1626874f2f1011e7937712000d3b863-200559730.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   a1626874f2f1011e7937712000d3b863-200559730.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 52.207.24.56
Name:   a1626874f2f1011e7937712000d3b863-200559730.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Address: 34.202.99.171

$ host -t ns aws.qianalysis.com
aws.qianalysis.com name server ns-1514.awsdns-61.org.
aws.qianalysis.com name server ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk.
aws.qianalysis.com name server ns-244.awsdns-30.com.
aws.qianalysis.com name server ns-842.awsdns-41.net.

$ dig +trace aws.qianalysis.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.14-Ubuntu <<>> +trace aws.qianalysis.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           27722   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           27722   IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20170516050000 20170503040000 14796 . gCBRAPt6Mu2qkxfuwDohzVqCpvUeVKZmnNSYWtl/8w9oF5YKsFpyBrvE OvbTO7hcdlz6Vpz0VqEkUUTvRlzD+HTj/s4CD8lg+I2p+9+mbK/CRjx1 uPhgNhWg+/ZaLTa5CPLbZGYfoyJhYcNKItmYpzbDQK6BJuZUhTetbjtF 8JgakLBcO7ptWzaLA0XwF7mVbbYK4IeFa7Ue2QfdQbaTsqiNm/ijGOTE pFhKQfeKI/4XlwAN+87QkKoPNDAjIYVQFbX9BeQd3i4PXa6Q3gJ4HHAr Weg6fjp363c6V4VJzA7LCSARq/ry4fuG1CoaX8jtkmeM49BYpp8GzpcC 0VvcHA==
;; Received 525 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) in 4566 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            86400   IN  DS  30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.            86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20170516050000 20170503040000 14796 . Ge+3ma50QY0R9ekOoiDuzGxpx5eT7euTgFWbA3qmwf0RdY3bTGDWHSt4 pcOCnO7es7Fr8mTkBSsVQXwfzk9L7dOb4nQ8TUTykRsP7UdYxLn9gIb6 Z//gtpb/BIKhieYXQgCKLDueGinJPFT+0tBN+k+hdgG7rY5xoU0yn/lm 9Wc6v0ElTe563IDUMnoa1OMCIj+wIEWO9YuFOXaPUEz8Uk/S5pNcTvcb MoKXcQFOwlbZU5208+fteMGQ2S2J4DTyDtxK/Ir4qA3w6HwABxCJpmn2 DIFQK2VOppKBaaxiUXvZvNu76SgTYYNgvDXGITLNVaLGUDv6TuTm303y +FLDCA==
;; Received 870 bytes from 192.203.230.10#53(e.root-servers.net) in 4418 ms

qianalysis.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.digitalocean.com.
qianalysis.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.digitalocean.com.
qianalysis.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.digitalocean.com.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20170509044753 20170502033753 27302 com. nv2pLmsvfV0zhb2xG3WCHTVrVnGMA+6Eb6BeHy/+omyHt+d/6jTq9BzF e+xLLHGj7ddu8ugKRcEP0KawgsMYvgaxLFQfTJIis1SvdQdybpOMqCfT e1MQM/OCauaRhqM8XQZIWolPPgYEpfMELfvW8b+xqVs8YfWJnyCWXdJQ 94s=
LER81PJG42CMP2MD94DCJVIJMNNFLDL4.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - LERCERUAETGQB9VTEU76H1KTP6J0607R NS DS RRSIG
LER81PJG42CMP2MD94DCJVIJMNNFLDL4.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20170509041957 20170502030957 27302 com. Wvwv68vG1/oBfNUrnp+KvP8LYMAOgTIYnqbvOrWn48MrfDpokXNzbIvu PJ9N8w0RUTZh/H6VsdpSLNVnO+xcii4lX6b9HyJC4H8KFy3//N57STjn BJZEEqs977mYLzNWQnBth0CJndLZ2PilQqBkPnknAVoJPlDpzyBjF3nm IfE=
;; Received 731 bytes from 192.5.6.30#53(a.gtld-servers.net) in 6894 ms

aws.qianalysis.com. 1800    IN  NS  ns-842.awsdns-41.net.
aws.qianalysis.com. 1800    IN  NS  ns-244.awsdns-30.com.
aws.qianalysis.com. 1800    IN  NS  ns-1514.awsdns-61.org.
aws.qianalysis.com. 1800    IN  NS  ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk.
;; Received 184 bytes from 173.245.58.51#53(ns1.digitalocean.com) in 4818 ms

aws.qianalysis.com. 60  IN  A   52.207.24.56
aws.qianalysis.com. 60  IN  A   34.202.99.171
aws.qianalysis.com. 172800  IN  NS  ns-1514.awsdns-61.org.
aws.qianalysis.com. 172800  IN  NS  ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk.
aws.qianalysis.com. 172800  IN  NS  ns-244.awsdns-30.com.
aws.qianalysis.com. 172800  IN  NS  ns-842.awsdns-41.net.
;; Received 216 bytes from 205.251.192.244#53(ns-244.awsdns-30.com) in 104 ms
```

Seems like everything is configured properly. But can find out the main reason behind not being able to access the subdomain [aws.qianalysis.com](http://aws.qianalysis.com) and how to solve this.